# CSS: Allow scrolling of DIV behind a fixed DIV through the fixed DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a full-height scrollable DIV behind a smaller fixed DIV. The scrollable DIV is scrollable when I have the cursor over it, but it is not scrollable when the cursor is over the fixed DIV.

**My question: Is there a way via CSS to allow the scrollable DIV to still be scrollable when the cursor is over the fixed DIV?**

Below is an image to show the layout in question.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any code? if yes then please put here so we can elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work normally, please see the div structure

```
    <div class="wrapper-div">
        <div class="fixed-div">
            <div class="text-container">Fixed div</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .wrapper-div {
            background: #F00; 
            width: 100%; 
            height: 120vh; 
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .fixed-div {
            background: #0F0; 
            position: fixed; 
            bottom: 5vh; 
            width:80%; 
            margin-left: 10%; 
            height: 200px;
        }

        .text-container {
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
```